# What causes "Transport endpoint is not connected" in ZeroMQ?

Tags: sockets, security, zeromq, denial-of-service

I am working on a product which uses ZeroMQ (version 4.0.1).

The server and client communicate based on ZeroMQ `ROUTER`-socket.

To read socket events, server and client also create socket-monitor sockets (`PAIR`). There are three ports on which server binds and listens. Out of these three ports, one port is in a non-secured mode. Other two ports are using `md5`-authentication.

The issue I am facing is that, both the server and the client spontaneously receive socket disconnect for one of the secure port sockets (please see a log below). I have checked multiple times that server and client both have L3 reachability to each other.

What else I should check for?
What really triggers this error scenario?

```
zmq_print_callback:ZmQ: int zmq::stream_engine_t::read(void*, size_t):923
                        Stream engine recv():
                        TCP socket (187) to unknown:0 was disconnected
                        with error 107 [Transport endpoint is not connected]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below sequence of events can trigger this error on server

1. Server receives ACCEPTED event for clientY and gets FD1.
2. Link-flap/network issue happens and clientY disconnects but server does not receive this disconnect.
3. Network recovers and clientY connects back to server.
4. Server receives ACCEPTED event for clientY and gets FD2. However, packets sent to this sockets does not go out of the server.
5. After 1 min or so, clientY receives "Transport endpoint is not connected error" for FD1.
6. Application can use this to treat as client disconnect.